# How to speed up numpy tensor*tensor operation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba

I have a bottleneck in my code it is numpy 3d array multiplication by `* operator` with numpy 3d array.
I wanted to speed up this part of the program with numba @njit or @jit decorator, but it decreased performance in 2 times.
Slow part of the code:

```
@numba.jit
def mat_mul_and_sum(img1, img2, alpha):
    return img1*(1-alpha) + img2*alpha
```

img1, img2, and alpha are 3d np.array with the same shapes.
Is it possible to speed up this line of code?

Comment: IIRC numba will not improve the performance of NumPy operations.

Comment: What ist the shape of the tensors? If some dimensions are small further speedup will be possible.

Comment: @max9111 Dimensions are 1920x1080x3 dtype is uint8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you unroll the loops as follows, for an array size of (100, 100, 100), numba is twice as fast as the pure numpy version, likely due to the fact that no intermediate arrays need to be allocated:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def mat_mul_and_sum(img1, img2, alpha):
    return img1*(1-alpha) + img2*alpha


@nb.jit
def mat_mul_and_sum2(img1, img2, alpha):
    NI, NJ, NK = img1.shape
    out = np.empty((NI, NJ, NK))

    for i in range(NI):
        for j in range(NJ):
            for k in range(NK):
                out[i,j,k] = img1[i,j,k] * (1.0 - alpha[i,j,k]) + img2[i,j,k] * alpha[i,j,k]

    return out
```

and then testing:

```
N = 100
img1 = np.random.normal(size=(N, N, N))
img2 = np.random.normal(size=(N, N, N))
alpha = np.random.normal(size=(N, N, N))

A = mat_mul_and_sum(img1, img2, alpha)
B = mat_mul_and_sum2(img1, img2, alpha)

np.allclose(A,B) #True

%timeit mat_mul_and_sum(img1, img2, alpha)
# 4.6 ms ± 44.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit mat_mul_and_sum2(img1, img2, alpha)
# 2.4 ms ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Update:**
You can also try changing the decorator to `nb.jit(parallel=True)` and then replace the outer loop with `for i in nb.prange(NI):`, which on my machine drops the results from `timeit` to 1.37 ms. This and other timings will certainly differ from machine to machine and also on the size of the inputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestions also speed up computation on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

One option is actually using `numba` the way it's supposed to be used (not just applying a decorator).  However for your particular function you can make use of multicore rendering using the [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) package.

---

```
import numexpr as ne

def mat_mul_and_sum_numexpr(a, b, alpha):
    return ne.evaluate('a*(1-alpha) + b*alpha')
```

---

Using the timings from the other answer:

```
In [11]: %timeit mat_mul_and_sum(img1, img2, alpha)
21.6 ms ± 955 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit mat_mul_and_sum2(img1, img2, alpha)
6.35 ms ± 126 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [13]: %timeit mat_mul_and_sum_numexpr(img1, img2, alpha)
4.22 ms ± 54.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [14]: np.allclose(mat_mul_and_sum(img1, img2, alpha), mat_mul_and_sum_numexpr(img1, img2, alpha))
Out[14]: True
```

---

You might be able to squeeze out some extra performance with `numba`s parallelization, but oftentimes using `numexpr` provides a nice performance boost without requiring any code re-write.